# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended (extremely basic query)

Tags: sql, oracle

My query is just

```
select * from table;
```

Why would I be getting this error?

Comment: I'd bet there is something missing from what is generating the error. Can you give more context?

Answer (score 1):

In which context are you using this command?

Possibly the trainling ";" is the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ORA-00933, but is it possible that *table* is an Oracle keyword and you cannot have a table named *table*?

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00933_sql_command_ended.htm

Comment: I think `table` is just his placeholder in the example.